# Force asynchronous socket read to finish early using Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I have a `tcp::socket` for reading and writing data. There is a read loop made up by chaining `async_read_some()` and the handler `on_data_read()` that calls `async_read_some()` again after dealing with the data read. A relevant `shared_ptr<tcp::socket>` is passed along the loop. The loop ends when `on_data_read()` is called with a non-success `error_code` such as `asio::error::eof`, in which case `async_read_some()` is not called.

There may also be asynchronous writes on the socket, which is done by repeated calls to `async_write_some()` until all data is written. That is, the handler `on_data_written()` for `async_write_some()` calls `async_write_some()` again if the data is only partially written. The relevant `shared_ptr<tcp::socket>` is also passed along the call-chain.

Now, I want to close the socket in a safe manner. Specifically, I want to force the asynchronous read to finish early with a non-success error code to ends the read loop. If there is no pending write call-chain, the only `shared_ptr<tcp::socket>` (the one passed along the read loop) gets destroyed with its managed `tcp::socket` closed and destroyed. If there is a pending write call-chain, it continues until all data is written. At the time the write call-chain goes to its end, the last `shared_ptr<tcp::socket>` (the one passed along the write call-chain) gets destroyed. This procedure is safe in the sense that the socket is closed after pending writes, if any.

The problem is

- how can I force the asynchronous socket read to finish with a non-success error code?

I've checked the [linger](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/linger.html) option. But it won't work since I'm using chained-up `async_write_some()` instead of a single `async_write()`. So, the socket may be closed while `on_data_written()` is being called. `cancel()` and `close()` won't work either, since they interrupt not only the read loop but also the write call-chain. And although `shutdown()` can be applied to the read loop only, it prevents future `async_read_some()` calls only, and has no effect on what is already done. I've worked out a workaround solution. That is, call `cancel()`, but have `on_data_written()` ignore the the error code caused by `cancel()` and continue the write call-chain. I'm not satisfied with this solution (see the remarks section [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel/overload2.html)). I'm wondering if there is a more direct and elegant way to achieve what I want, or the whole design is just flawed?

Comment: The linger option has nothing to do with reads whatsoever. It is about what happens when you close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you've summed it up pretty nicely.

You cannot really do better than fullblown cancel. Indeed you may resume any canceled writes.

I don't think there is anything more elegant. I would not say the design is flawed, but you might want to consider not actually canceling pending operations, but instead just keeping a flag to indicate whether a "logical read cancel" is pending and prevent chaining more reads in that case

Comment: Thanks for the response. But not chaining more reads does not actually help. The question lies in interrupting or breaking an already chained read ~>_<~

Answer (score 0):

When you used shutdown.. eg.. socket.shutdown  did you use the shutdown_both?

(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec)

The shutdown_both option.  That should handle read and write closures.

```
socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, errorcode);
if (errorcode)
{
    cerr << "socket.shutdown error: " << errorcode.message() << endl;
}
```

Also.. If you have the io_service handle.  you can call io_service.stop() as a last resort which will shutdown all operations.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown the socket for input. That will cause all pending reads to encounter end of stream and return accordingly.

> And although shutdown() can be applied to the read loop only, it prevents future async_read_some() calls only, and has no effect on what is already done.

I don't know where you got this misinformation from. I don't even know what it means. Shutdown applies to the socket, not a read loop.

Comment: *cause all pending reads to encounter end of stream and return accordingly*. On my friend's Mac OS, yes. On my Windows 7 64bit, No.